# Перенаправление на другую страницу с передачей значения инпута

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу сделать переход на другую страницу по клику на кнопку, с выводом value нужного мне инпута в другой инпут?

Comment: Если вы будете использовать jquery, то просто добавьте значение Input как параметр к URL страницы, а при загрузке страницы просто считайте это значение и поместите в Input

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, я примерно думал так поступить, но как можно непосредственно передавать это значение в url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сперва надо получить значение из инпута:

```
var text = $('#InputId').val(); //лучше добавить ID для элемента
```

После этого добавляем значение к URL, для этого получаем текущий URL и проверяем есть ли у него параметры:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf('?') === -1)
            url += '?text=' + text;
        else
            url  += '&text=' + text;
```

После этого идет редирект на другую страницу:

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

На второй странице надо добавить функцию получения параметра:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
        return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
    }
}
```

};

И потом записать параметр в input:

```
var text = getUrlParameter('text');
$('#InputId').val(text);
```